# Compare the element of an Array of arrays and count the frequency of a element

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My problem:

```
var rawData = [[two],[three],[four],[one],[two],[two],[two],[three],[four],[five],[three],[four],[five]];
```

Suppose I have this **arrays of array** from where I have to find the unique elements of an array and total count of that unique element in the array in the form of two respective arrays such as

```
var queslist = [one,two,three,four,five...]
var count = [countOfOne, countOfTwo, countOfThree, countOfFour, countOfFive...]
```

(Keep in mind the rawData is dynamic as Im getting the data from a large spreadsheet)
What should be the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: Don't change the goal post.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this? Both examples can also be done with reduce which I find harder to read.

```js
let list = {}
const rawData = ["two","three","four","one","two","two","two","three","four","five","three","four","five"]
  .forEach(item => {
    const obj = list[item] || { count: 0 };
    obj.count = obj.count ? obj.count + 1 : 1;
    list[item] = obj;
  });


 ["one","two","three","four","five"].forEach(item => console.log(item,list[item]))
```

Ignoring stuff not in the compare arrray

```js
let list = {}
const compareList  = ["two","three"];
const rawData = ["two","three","four","one","two","two","two","three","four","five","three","four","five"]
  .forEach(item => {
    if (compareList.indexOf(item) !=-1) {
      const obj = list[item] || { count: 0 };
      obj.count = obj.count ? obj.count + 1 : 1;
      list[item] = obj;
    }
  });


 console.log(list)
```